# Sort key-value pair of a Bundle in android

Tags: android

I have a list of key-value pairs in a Bundle

> params.keySet()

which needs to be sorted alphabetically on the key column.

I tried the long way of extracting the key-value pairs and sorting them using

> Collections.sort(list)

and putting it back inside a new Bundle.

But when I call params.keySet(). They come to un-sorted again. Any ideas. Is their an easy way?

Comment: Add some more code to better see context of what you are doing.

Comment: Why do you need this behavior from a Bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bundle` is backed up by a `HashMap`, so it does not guarantee the order of keys. You'll have to reconsider the logic in your app to break the dependency on the order of the keys in the Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

`public Set<String> keySet ()`
`Set` only guarantees no duplicates but not order.

For your requirement, you can use some subclass of `java.util.SortedMap` instead of `Bundle`.

Comment: Yes, and to my experience it returns ordered key-value pairs.